# MPI-Parallel HDF5: H5Pset_fapl_mpio equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, mpi, hdf5

I want to use parallel HDF5 on a distributed memory cluster for the output of my MPI application. I'm familiar with the C-interface, but wanted to try the C++ API as well.

However, I got stuck when trying to "convert" this command `H5Pset_fapl_mpio( p_list, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_INFO_NULL );` into C++. I was not able to find the corresponding call in the API.

How is the MPI communicator properly handed to HDF5 via the C++ interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent at this stage, as some of the MPI calls are not yet ported to the C++ API (according to recent discussions like [this one](https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/creating-a-group-per-mpi-process-using-parallel-hdf5-with-the-c-api/4900/3)). You have to remember that until very recently, there was no support of MPI in the C++ layer.

You may also want to have a look at htpp://h5cpp.ca as it may support also your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) which fully supports parallel HDF5 (i.e. HDF5+MPI). It will also alleviate you from low-level details such as setting certain parameters through `H5Pset_fapl_mpio` (HDFql will do it for you).

You can find an example that illustrates how to use HDFql in parallel (i.e. MPI) in C++ [here](http://www.hdfql.com/examples).